# AmCharts Map type error

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

I am using AmCharts Maps to build a map of the world. The map displays and works correctly, until I add a list of areas. am using the following configuration to initialize the map using the AmCharts React component.

```
var config = {
    type: 'map',
    dataProvider: {
        map: 'worldLow',
        areas: [{id: 'US'}]
    },
    areasSettings: {
        autoZoom: false,
        selectedColor: '#FF0000',
        selectable: false
    }
}
```

In the console I get a TypeError coming from the maps file; specifically the function is `addObjectEventListeners`.

The full error is:

`TypeError:a.mousedown(...).mouseup(...).mouseover(...).mouseout(...).touchend(...).touchstart(...).keyup is not a function`

Most of this comes from the tutorial they have  https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/your-first-ammap/

What am I doing wrong to cause the TypeError? I have debugged the `a` object but from what I can tell, it is the same as from their example on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7fb82b47d1e7394f45b51e65adee2e2a).

NOTE: AmCharts and AmMaps are working correctly without the areas array being passed in. I have also tried using the SVG version of the map, but the same issue occurs. I also replaced the config used in the example CodePen with my own, which worked perfectly.

#### Update

II swapped out the `ammap_amcharts_extension.js` with the full `ammap.js` and things seem to be working. Potentially this is an isolated issue to only using the extension. I am using AmCharts (Pie and Serial) on the page as well, so I initially only wanted to use the extension as it is a smaller file size.

Comment: Yes, just using `ammap_amcharts_extension.js` doesn't work.  `ammap_amcharts_extension.js` is only used if your page has both charts and maps as it extends the classes in `amcharts.js` to add map functionality as `ammap.js` and `amcharts.js` will override each other if included at the same time. The extension file can't stand alone, so if you're just using maps, then use `ammap.js`.

Comment: I am loading amcharts.js on the page well; so initially I was only additionally adding the extension. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Also to clarify, the extension works in the sense that I can create a map. Adding the areas is what causes the TypeError when using the extension version.

Comment: Just a note: the `ammap_amcharts_extension.js` must go **after** `amcharts.js` include. If it's the other way around, it might have been causing all kinds of anomalies.

Comment: I can confirm that all the scripts were being loaded the correct order. I think there is just an issue with the extension file.

Comment: Extension file works fine: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ba4f21be899345e0a0e2494ada595110 So I'm assuming it might be something related to React implementation. I'll kick this over to React developer to check.

Comment: The React plugin seems to work fine: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ea81cac690cb329e8d078adcefe49b49 Could you please give more information, such as the code that you are using. Ideally the code would contain the minimal amount needed to trigger the bug.